# On Windows Mobile while on a phone call how do you play an mp3 file so that the other party can hear it?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I'd like to be able to pre-record a message in a wav or mp3 file, then make a phone call and play this message to the other party when they receive the call. Is that possible?